# Unable to find object even though it is declared in same class

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm currently learning how to build GUI's in Java and I'm encountering the following error "cannot find symbol - Class Listener".

The following code creates radio buttons and then pairs them with a JLabel and an action listener. However even though I provide listener as an argument to button, the compiler is telling me it cannot find the listener class. Does anyone know why this is?

The error is occuring on the parameter line of the button method. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
private void build(Stadium stadium)
    {  

       Listener listener = new Listener();

       add(button("Front", listener));
       add(button("Middle", listener));
       add(button("Back", listener));

    }

    private JRadioButton button(String label, Listener listener)
    {   JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton(label);
        button.addActionListener(listener);
        group.add(button);
        return button;  }
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ActionListener` not `Listener` , their is nothing like `Listener` in GUI.

```
private void build(Stadium stadium)
{  

   ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Here you implement what you want your listener to execute on  button click;
        }
    };

   add(button("Front", listener));
   add(button("Middle", listener));
   add(button("Back", listener));

}

private JRadioButton button(String label, Listener listener)
{   JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton(label);
    button.addActionListener(listener);
    group.add(button);
    return button;  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an ActionListener, not a Listener. Your class should implement ActionListener
(`public class GUI implements ActionListener {` )

and then implement the actionPerformed method.

add the instance of this class as listener.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to import `Listener`

Comment: I've imported the relevant packages but to no avail